# Firebase database rules to enforce foreign key access

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to force foreign key access where a User can only see the record that they created.

When trying the below config for `.read` it will say `PermissionDenied` each time. Based upon the docs [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html) it seems like this config should work.

Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "emails": {
      ".indexOn": ["userId"],
      "$email": {
        ".read": "data.child('userId').val() === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

JSON data:

```
{
  "emails" : {
    "-K_RIN22BBoI3M7JCt6W" : {
      "email" : "a@a.com",
      "userId" : "S2hOJpLdXlghmmPb8r20cJLzJTB2"
    },
    "-K_RImdpfGrln0AlUZqp" : {
      "email" : "b@b.com",
      "userId" : "eCD2aHZANada1xKXBLdsR7XMzMu1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your rules should allow read access to individual emails. However, you won't be able to query for a list of emails for a specific user, as the query would need to read all of the entries to determine which ones match and which ones don't.